# How to quickly batch save Bitmaps?

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, system.drawing

So I have a source bitmap that is fairly large, so I shrink it down by a scale of %25 to speed things along in image processing and what not. At the end, I have a group of Rectangles (around 2000) that correspond to sections of the scaled image. I am trying to rescale the Rectangles to match the same areas on the source, then saving that area as a cropped image.

This was my initial code that saved cropped images of the scaled image:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].Count; j++)
    {
        Cell cell = cells[i][j];

        if (cell.width < 0 || cell.height < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(cell.width, cell.height);

        using (Graphics c = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            c.DrawImage(inputBitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, cell.width, cell.height), new Rectangle(cell.x1, cell.y1, cell.width, cell.height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        bitmap.Save(cellDirectory + "\\cell" + i.ToString("D2") + j.ToString("D2") + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

This is my code changed to save the cropped image of the original bitmap:

```
for (int i = 0; i < cells.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cells[i].Count; j++)
    {
        Cell cell = cells[i][j];

        if (cell.width < 0 || cell.height < 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        int x = cell.x1 * 4;
        int y = cell.y1 * 4;
        int width = cell.width * 4;
        int height = cell.height * 4;

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);

        using (Graphics c = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            c.DrawImage(input, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }

        bitmap.Save(cellDirectory + "\\cell" + i.ToString("D2") + j.ToString("D2") + ".png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
}
```

The program with the first code finishes in about 20 seconds on average, but for some reason the second version takes over 6 minutes. My brain math might be lying to me, but that seems to be a disproportionate time increase.

The debugging that I have done so far has revealed to me that this line:

```
c.DrawImage(input, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), new Rectangle(x, y, width, height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
```

is taking longer to complete over time. I suspect that some sort of memory leak could be causing this, but I have tried manually calling Dispose on every object I can and nothing helped. Is there some kind of under-the-hood thing that I should be aware of that is causing this?

Comment: Did you try monitoring memory usage over time?  Task manager would be enough for start...

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't show Dispose() on Bitmap.  Did you try that?

Comment: I listed my initial code before I did this, but yes, I have tried calling Dispose() on both bitmap and c (even though the using block should handle c on its own).

Comment: @DanielMošmondor I ran the program while keeping a close eye on the CPU Usage and every Memory Working Set column the task manager had, and rather than going up, the CPU usage stayed constant, while the working sets actually decreased over time (by a marginal amount, but still).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original method saves a file at the original resolution, while the new method increases both width and height by a factor of 4, which is a 16x increase in the image size. The time difference (6 minutes vs 20 seconds) is roughly proportional:

```
(6 * 60) / 20 = 18 times slower
4 * 4         = 16 times the image size
```

Comment: That explains the increase in processing time, but not the increasing amount of time it takes to draw each bitmap.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that part of the question. Could it be the instantiation of all those rectangles? Perhaps you need `using (Rectangle src=...,Rectangle dest=...)`. Does this happen in both implementations?

Comment: I've tried that, but Rectangle can't be used in a using block in this way, since it doesn't implement IDisposable.

Comment: If the cells are of variable size, is it possible that the larger ones are later in the array and that's the cause of the slowdown? If they're all the same size, you may be able to speed up processing by retaining your `Bitmap `and `Graphics` objects for the entire process...

Comment: I found the AForge Library, and it has a Crop class that takes a fraction of the time on the larger image than it did on the smaller one, so I'm gonna go with that one. Thanks for the help.